# How to check valid email domain in asp.net MVC?

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4, email

I have checked email validation by using this snippet of Code.

```html
[RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid e-mail adress")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [DisplayName("Email")]
        public virtual string Email { get; set; }
```

but using this code (a@b.com) is a valid email. But originally there is no domain naming b. How can I make sure that the email domain is valid.

Comment: You would need to do a DNS lookup on the domain `b.com`, check that it has an `MX` record and -- if you want to be sure the address exists -- initiate an SMTP connection and see if it'll accept it as an `RCPT TO` parameter.

Comment: Use the `[EmailAddress]` attribute! As far as checking a domain is valid, you will need to check that on the server when you post back (and use a `[Remote]` attribute if you want client side validation as well)

Comment: I have used the [EmailAddress] attribute.

Comment: No you haven't. All you have shown is `[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]` which will just add `type="email"` to the input if you use `EditorFor()`. And for details on how to do a DNS lookup for a domain, refer [documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find whether b.com exists you have to query whether MX records exists for b.com 
You have to send such queries to name server .
There are API's  available to check whether a particular domain has MX records or
not. This will do the work for you